Calculating FX Forwards Using Spot Prices and Discount Factors for Exotic Currency Pairs
We need to value FX forwards for some exotic currency pairs using a third-party system that does not provide the forward rates. The system can provide spot prices. Is it correct (real) to calculate the theoretical forward price by multiplying the spot price by the ratio of discount factors of the counter currency over the base currency?
Additionally, where can I source the risk-free interest rates? Can I infer the risk-free interest rates from the zero curve by examining the yields from two notable maturities around the value date of the forward and interpolate to get the rate? This process would be repeated once daily for valuation purposes.
Do you know any free services that provide yields for zero-coupon rates of various nations, including more exotic ones? Is this procedure correct? What alternatives are there to address the lack of forward rates for certain currencies? Can the same zero curve also be used to estimate the discount factor for an FX forward?

Have you tried asking LSEG https://www.lseg.com/en/fx/data former Refinitiv/Reuters?

I faced the same problem long go for emerging markets currencies where simply no one trades FX fowarrds, like Paraguay and Bolivia.  I suggest you ltalk to LSEG (obscure currencies won't be on WM/Reuters Benchmarks, but they still might offer some quotes), also  ask ion https://iongroup.com/products/markets/wallstreet-fx/ and stoneX https://www.stonex.com/foreign-exchange-market/ if they can give you some indicative quotes.
